# Registering weak_ptr observer in constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, listener, shared-ptr, observer-pattern

I'm trying to rewrite our Observer / Observable implementation to use std::shared_ptr/std::weak_ptr to get rid of some nasty race conditions currently present in the code.

Typically, the observers registers themselves when some condition is met or when they are constructing child objects like so:

```
// Used to be raw 'this' now child instead derives a weak_ptr and stores it
child->addObserver(shared_from_this())
```

And unregisters themselves in destructor like so:

```
child->removeObserver(this); // Not shared_from_this() since in destructor
```

In some situations this works fine, however in many instances the observer wants to register itself when in constructor. Since the shared_ptr hasn't been created yet we cannot call shared_from_this().

Since the weak_ptr is commonly recomended to implement the observer pattern in C++ I'm wondering what the idiomatic way to solve the above problem is.

Some thoughts:

- Let factory that creates the observer object register the observer. This leaks abstractions from the observer (why should the factory know who the child wants to observe?) and forces observer to expose internal objects that it may want to observe
- Add an init method that gets called by factory after constructor is complete, better than above but what is the semantic difference between a constructor and init anyway? What should be done where? Is it even RAII? Indeed, some languages even call their constructors init.
- Pass a lambda to constructor that takes another lambda that gets called after construction
- Some template magic maybe?
- Implement the observer pattern in some other way.

Comment: workaround: two step initialization. Or change architecture and setup observer relation by third party code (code which instantiate this class).

Comment: @jxh maybe I'm confusing terms here, but child is the object that wants to nofify "us". To be notified we call the child's addObserver method with a shared_ptr (which will be derived into a weak_ptr) of an observer (us).

Comment: Can you provide more context? Why constructor creates children immediately? Is it possible there is zero children? Can you add/remove children after construction? Are children some kind of abstraction (represented by interface) or is is always the same type? Are the children visible from outside? Do you rely need manage them by `shared_ptr` (why not `unique_ptr` and observer as raw pointer)?

Comment: @MarekR "_some nasty race conditions currently present in the code._" is the key hint here: "observer as raw pointer" would fail to get rid of the race, probably!

Comment: You can't upgrade a `weak_ptr`. You'll need a different design. I understand that you don't want a list of raw pointers to observers protected by a mutex?

Comment: @monoceres 1) Is copying of these observed objects possible? 2) If not, is move supported?

Comment: @curiousguy: this was less important question (that is why it was at the end) and you misunderstood it (raw pointer is equivalent of `weak_ptr` when `unique_ptr` is used) and this is decently not related with race conditions.

Comment: @MarekR How does a simpler pointer ("raw pointer"), just a pointer, accomplish anything related with `weak_ptr`? The role of a "weak reference" is not to "break cycles" (which isn't a thing), it's to be able to detect that the target is gone. A "weak reference" can be a tested for "null" (object gone), a pointer cannot. There might be over ways to test whether the object is gone, maybe by checking a global registry. But then there is that race condition thing: the object might disappear after we checked. Which is something `unique_ptr` cannot prevent.

Comment: In a MT program, an object that is changed by one thread and can be observed by multiple thread can be protected by a mutex inside the object, as long as the lifetime of the object is guaranteed to be a long as any client might want to use it, which is where `shared_ptr` is useful (or another refcount tool). The mention of "nasty race conditions" tells us that there is either real MT or some interleaving of tasks in one thread where each agent can act on common resources without a global manager with centralized data.

Comment: @curiousguy: when you have `unique_ptr` and parent is gone, then child is gone too, that is why raw pointer can be use as weak counterpart. See this [cppcon](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE). Please answer other questions which are more important (update question).

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with the problem as you have asked it is to create an explicit observer object instance held by a `shared_ptr` and contained in the "parent". The observer object would dispatch observations to the parent.

However, since the child is registering a `shared_ptr` to a `weak_ptr`, there is actually no need for the parent to remove itself as an observer explicitly. When the child is sending out notifications to observers, it checks if the `weak_ptr` is valid first. If it is no longer valid, it can remove the observer in situ instead of notifying.

```
void notify_observers (Event e) const {
    auto o = observers_.begin();
    auto erase = [this](decltype(o) o) {
        return observers_.erase(o);
    };
    while (o != observers_.end()) {
        if (auto l = o->lock()) ++o, l->notify(e);
        else o = locked_call(erase, o);
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTRbtowFH3nK@6Y1JoVkLZHYJGmCW0PlUDbY1sh41zAqhOniUOLEPt1dm2HxF7b5QES@9zjc869iSiK0VaI80eZC1WnCDOpK1Miz5Jet5ZhpstDuKJkZSJEbfAlOWNeZzDfY27gCD/nt7cLOE17PWKshYElL91OD@iqTDqZVDtaSleFKWd@M4EK1WY1dZAGzwYw8cvM7GQ1hLsHNh6PB8fTAI6nCCl0XrXnXNk6f89a5J@O9CukuOG1MtFpV6ALLLnRJQFeER6hRFOXOXyyUqbgSfdappBrIzcHYN4@DhqfrVehawOzGdhC@9@fwFYT0MH7dgXtz/V9fu0Fee5WzXuBkROvstXmI6T6IPvvO6nSRhI1i68VekbXOVBaPDapR7u2zzN394z8MTw3Ab2usNxjWTWFBrNCcUMuzKHAnGcIi@UQLg/UMvj268fvxIF5bbQ7ldwIrhSwxZK8Dh3EQnm5rS7ORgm1SijLxHTB7JYdgFcROxfbmpfprPOWwJa5jcG0RTdBBVxh5D6rbmZce3maLhrDwN7rRRFKchaLutqt1lw80jTd2dY/sNYKoYtgpLo8x20VYab2FbpwBomxFjQkmlB/MI6rljQYzGZcYqGaBAYK1riVOQsicyAaxQrfcKIHoN924ipoP3LxTAEjMA0fojMxT1nUVHvJDTA/LFbgKLEJWNTNjR6CGiXeJ8NAqr1QkVDrKUzMiRmS1A57anKzr4qkeDIuc9f6YBJE9IEo/JMYBxPBLg3otDfop@6ouOIpEBF9H/qjEcxfCqSX9ovvohTcSOrZfd4P2f7tMHMf3GgS3iP@HBG3vP/hPJ3PfwE)

Comment: Why not remove expired observers from the list immediately?

Comment: @curiousguy: It's less complicated. In particular, you don't have to worry about the Rule of Three.

Comment: I did not even consider that aspect. 1) Is copying of these observed objects possible? 2) If not, is move supported?

Comment: @curiousguy: I am unsure. Likely you need a special copy constructor that initializes the smart pointer properly.